# Swift Combine and iOS version limitations?

Tags: ios, swift, version, combine

For example AppTrackingTransparency exists in iOS 14+ but an app supports iOS 13+.

I used the following code:

```
@available(iOS 14, *)
    func requestATTPermissions() ->
    Future<ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus, Never> {
    ...
}

if #available(iOS 14, *) {
            requestATTPermissions()
                .sink { [weak self] _ in
                    self?.completion?()
                }
                .store(in: &combineSubscriptionCollector.subscriptions)
        } else {
            completion?()
        }
```

But is it possible to move `if #available(iOS 14, *) {` into `Future`/`AnyPublisher` which in iOS 13 works like `Just(())` and in iOS14+ requests ATT? Somehow like this:

```
Just(()).map {
  if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    return requestATTPermissions()
       .map { status in ... }
  } else {
    return Just(())
  }
}
.sink { [weak self] _ in
    self?.completion?()
}
.store(in: &combineSubscriptionCollector.subscriptions)
```

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would like to use this, after you "moved `if #available(iOS 14, *) {` into `Future`/`AnyPublisher`"? It's not clear what that phrase means.

Comment: Do you want to move the `#available` check into `requestATTPermissions`? If that's the case, you'd need to change its return type to something else. It can't use `ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus`.

Comment: @Sweeper added an example. Removing `ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus` allows even to move `if #available(iOS 14, *)` into a func which returns `Future` in my case but it is not always appropriate.

Comment: Wait, so you are not using the `ATTrackingManager.AuthorizationStatus` at all? You are always going to call `completion` in the same way, whether or not the authorization succeeded?

Comment: @Sweeper sorry, missed `map` which should handle status

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just need to use `flatMap` instead of `map`:

```
Just(()).flatMap { _ in
    if #available(iOS 14, *) {
        return requestATTPermisions().map { status in
            // do not return anything here...
        }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
    } else {
        return Just(()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
    }
}
// .sink and .store...
```

Though I think this is easier to read and understand:

```
let publisher: AnyPublisher<(), Never>
if #available(iOS 14, *) {
    publisher = requestATTPermisions().map { status in
        // ...
    }.eraseToAnyPublisher()
} else {
    publisher = Just(()).eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
publisher.sink { ... }.store(in: ...)
```

Comment: I your first case because It looks more universal. But I don't understand - I wrote the same code with `map` instead of `flatMap` and it writes `Cannot convert value of type 'AnyPublisher<(), Never>' to closure result type '()'`. Could you please explain the difference for this case?

Comment: @Gargo In `map`, you're supposed to return a new *value* for each of the values that got published (`(Output) -> TransformedOutput`). In `flatMap`, you're supposed to return a *publisher* for each of the values that got published (`(Output) -> some Publisher`).